The position of "encore" in a sentence
I've heard it's valid to either say "mais j'ai encore dormi" and "mais j'ai dormi encore"
but I do really wanna know what native French speakers would use the most

Note the difference between J'ai dormi encore ("I slept more") and Je dromais encore ("I was still sleeping")

@RogerV. are you sure they have different meanings?

I am not a native French speaker, but I think the following two sentences are possible Je dormais encore quand elle est rentrée du travail. vs. Je l'avais entendu claquer la porte, mais il était tôt et je dormi encore un peu, avant de me lever.

The most common would be j'ai encore dormi, especially if nothing follows. J'ai dormi encore un peu and J'ai encore un peu dormi are I guess similarly popular.
'J'ai dormi encore.' sounds a bit literary and in written material, the former leads at least since the middle of the 20th century (and even more than what the graph shows as false positives are included, like "[...] j'ai dormi. Encore [...]")


Il a utilisé Ngram Viewer encor, pour une réponse encore plus jolie, mais encore a-t-il dû éliminer les ... false positives. Si encore Ngram Viewer n'avait pas de false positives.
